# Table View Animation not working properly while adding ViewController on a Container View?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, animation

I have currently set up my tableview on the left side of the screen so that I can animate it from there as below:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    tblView.frame = CGRectMake(-self.view.frame.size.width, 48, self.tblView.frame.size.width, self.tblView.frame.size.height)
}
```

Now I have set up a button that animates the tableview from - self.view.frame.size.width to 0 as below and this works fine:

```
@IBAction func showMenu(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.tblView.hidden = false    
    if flag == false{
        showMenu()
    } else {
        hidemenu()
    }
}

func showMenu(){
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations:{
        self.tblView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 48, self.tblView.frame.size.width, self.tblView.frame.size.height)
    } )
    flag = true
}

func hidemenu(){
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations:{
        self.tblView.frame = CGRectMake(-self.view.frame.size.width, 48, self.tblView.frame.size.width, self.tblView.frame.size.height)
    } )
    flag = false
}
```

The problem is when I am trying to hide the menu after clicking on tableview cell as below:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var row = indexPath.row
    var storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    switch row {
    case 0:           
        hidemenu()
        println("hide menu")
        if firstVC == nil{
            firstVC  = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("firstVC") as? FirstViewController
        }
        activeViewController = firstVC
    default:
        println("no index")
    }
}
```

The tableview does not get hide towards the left instead the animation appears to be from right and ends in the 0. Instead I am seeking the animation from 0 to -self.view.frame.size.width position on x-axis.

hideMenu function gets called.

**EDITED:** After hours of debugging with None i found that my error is on the line when in did select method i assign the view controller to the content view of the containerView

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        hidemenu()
        var row = indexPath.row
        var storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        switch row {                
        case 0:             

            if firstVC == nil{

                firstVC  = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("firstVC") as? FirstViewController
            }                
            activeViewController = firstVC
.....           
}
```

I have variable declare as

```
 var activeViewController : UIViewController? {            
        didSet{
            removeInactiveViewController(oldValue)
            updateActiveViewController()
        }
    }

  func updateActiveViewController(){            

        if let activeVC = activeViewController{

            activeVC.view.frame = contentView.bounds
            contentView.addSubview(activeVC.view)//this line gives me error
            activeVC.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

        }

    }
```

**Going to drill down the error in the animation is while adding the activeVC on the content view as contentView.addSubview(activeVC.view). Sorry for lengthy post ..**

If i comment the line the animation works fine..But the view is not added to my main view...How do i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are applying animation by setting frame manually and you are already set AutoLayout constraints. so this is conflict internally. kindly removed your `UITableView` `constraints` from `storyboard` and it working fine.

Initial

[image]

and after removing constraints, it will look like.

[image]

Hope this help you.

Comment: @anishparajuli, your code is neat and clean. your code is seems to be write . so it difficult to figure out problem.

Comment: there may be some issues on logic :(

Comment: have you checked that `hidemenu()` called, once your `didSelect` method called?

Comment: yes..it is calling.......the interesting thing is i am getting result for the button...but why not when the cell is tapped?

Comment: @anishparajuli, have you checked that your `menushow()` will not called when you are tapping on `didselect` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76156/discussion-between-anish-parajuli-and-none).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76172/discussion-between-anish-parajuli-and-none).

Comment: @anishparajuli, you are setting frame by coding so there want be any need to set autolayout. removed your all UITableVIew Constraints and it working fine.

Comment: hey thanks man!!! but why doesnot the coding override the autolayout? what happened when i set up the auto layout so that animation went wrong? i need to know so that next time i shouldnot tackle a simple mistake whole afternoon

Comment: i am sorry..i was unable to test this answer last week..just doing right now...tried removing the constraints doesnot work..can you please do it and paste the project here for me ??

Comment: @anishparajuli, lets i need some time to upload source code

Comment: Here i will provide code that have autolayout in their storyboard as well programmatically set animation as well. will provide soon

Comment: yeah just my requirement will be fine

Comment: Here are you sample code.  kindly download from url. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7kttc3BOG13bDNObklfTmwzbnc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Earlier you did autolayout as well programmatically set frame so it cause conflict. in this sample code here i will set position programatically with NSlayout constraints + set constraints in storyboard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77066/discussion-between-anish-parajuli-and-none).

Comment: Thanks now it works well after few modification as requirement..oh..i must learn auto layout properly then....

Answer (score 0):

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        var row = indexPath.row
        var storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)


        self.tblView.hidden = true
        flag = false
         ........
}
```

and change this as

```
 @IBAction func showMenu(sender: AnyObject) {

        if self.tblView.hidden == true{
            self.tblView.frame = CGRectMake(-500, 48, self.tblView.frame.size.width, self.tblView.frame.size.height)

        }

        self.tblView.hidden = false

        if flag == false{

            displayMenu()

        }else{

          hidemenu()

        }

    }
```

Comment: This is bad approach, -500 may not be enough for some devices, you should always use size of the vies you are trying to animate. Also, how did this help OP? On every cell tap, you will hide whole tableview(without animation), move it -500 of its superview and then animate, display or hide in which case hide will do nothing, because tableview is -500 of screen

Comment: @IxPaka   yeah..this works but why not when i call the hide menu function which was working for the button action ?

Comment: self.tblView.frame = CGRectMake(-self.view.frame.size.width, 48, self.tblView.frame.size.width, self.tblView.frame.size.height)
Simply go with it then